# How to Create Header,Content, Side Bar and Footer section (layout) in .net MDI application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, mdi

I have one big existing application using .Net - MDI C#,

Now I am going to change some looks for application, so it looks better for client.

But I a, facing a lot of issues when I try to add more than 2 images on the Parent MDI Form.

How to create Header, Content, Side Bar and Footer Section in MDI (For. Ref.  find attach screenshot for application layout.)?  Also can anyone tell me which tips like which control I used for this type layout?

[image: **Click here to see ref. image screenshot for application layout**]

Answer (score 4):

You have been a member for 6 months, asked questions, but never answered a question,never commented on a question, and never even accepted an answer.

But if everyone in this community acted the same way, if everyone else was just a user, where would you be then?  There would be no community, no resource, you would never get an answer or have any information to search.  Think about it.  Then  think about actually joining the *community* and stop using it.

Now to answer your question, the Winforms MDI container does not natively support the functionality you are describing, however it does support siting UserControls directly on the MDI container. This makes emulating the functionality you describe very easy.  Just create a UserControl that provides the graphical surface and controls you need and then use the docking properties to force the MDI container to place child forms correctly in the open client area instead of on top of a UserControl.

For example, to create a logo and then a menu bar underneath create a UserControl with the logo and menu bar.  Create events and wire them up as needed to allow the MDI form to subscribe to events that pass any menu clicks back that the MDI form needs to handle.  Finally site the UserControl directly on the MDI form and set it's docking property to top.  Then any child forms will display correctly in the remaining client area underneath the menu bar on the UserControl.